# Jackson annotation to convert map data's into JSON values

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am learning Jackson library, and was trying with map data to converts it to JSON but I am getting equals sign in my json data

```
 Map<Integer,String> map=new HashMap();
 map.put(id++, "a_set.jsp?action=start");
 map.put(id++, "password_change.jsp?action=edit");
 map.put(id++, "logging.jsp?action=start");
 map.put(id++, "about.jsp");
 writeJson(map,resp);
```

and the writeJson method is

```
@JsonAnyGetter
private void writeJson(Object object, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        response.getWriter().write(object.toString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
            ProTrace.exception( CLASS_NAME + "Could not write to response", ex);

    }
}
```

Output is :

```
{
0=a_webuihost_set.jsp?action=start,
1=password_change.jsp?action=edit,
2=logging.jsp?action=start,
3=about.jsp
```

}

Why am i getting equals sign here?

Answer (score 0):

What you see is not `JSON` but `toString` representation of the `Map` object.
You need to use `JSON` serialisation library to serialise `POJO` to `JSON` payload. You can use `Jackson`'s `ObjectMapper`:

```
private void writeJson(Object object, HttpServletResponse response) {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), object);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        
    }
}
```